# SqlCeException-Expressions in the ORDER BY list cannot contain aggregate functions

Tags: sql-server, linq, nhibernate

I have the following code which counts vehicles grouped by vehicle type.

```
using (var uow = new UnitOfWork(new NHibernateHelper().SessionFactory)) {
    var repo = new Repository<Vehicle>(uow.Session);
    var vtSummary= repo.ListAll()
                .GroupBy(v => v.VehicleType.Name)
                .Select(v => new NameCount { 
                         EntityDescription = v.First().VehicleType.Name,
                         QtyCount = v.Count() })
                .OrderByDescending(v => v.QtyCount).ToList();
     uow.Commit();
     return vtSummary;
}
```

The above produces the following sql code:

```
SELECT VehicleType.Name as col_0_0_,
   CAST(COUNT(*) AS INT) as col_1_0_
FROM Vehicle vehicle0_
LEFT OUTER JOIN VehicleType vehicletype1_
  ON vehicle0_.VehicleTypeId= VehicleType.Id
GROUP  BY VehicleType.Name
ORDER  BY CAST(COUNT(*) AS INT) DESC
```

The SQL code runs perfectly well under MS SQL Server but testing under SQl CE it produces the following error:

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException : Expressions in the ORDER BY list cannot contain aggregate functions.
```

A solution from [Sub query in Sql server CE](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/2ac2cd28-1609-40bc-9628-6f747916e96f) is to specify an alias for the column and use the alias in the order by clause.

Is there any way to provide an alias in the LINQ expression that I am using to enable it run without raising errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform the OrderBy in memory, with LINQ to objects:

```
var vtSummary= repo.ListAll()
            .GroupBy(v => v.VehicleType.Name)
            .Select(v => new NameCount { 
                     EntityDescription = v.First().VehicleType.Name,
                     QtyCount = v.Count() })
            .AsEnumerable() //SQL executes at this point
            .OrderByDescending(v => v.QtyCount).ToList();
```